# How to access environment variables in angular?

Tags: variables, deployment, environment

I am trying to assign environment variables in a secure way but I was not able to do that in angular and windows.

Here is what I tried:

in termenal I set the aws s3 variables:

```
set secretAccessKey=????
```

and in my TypeScript file:

```
const secretAccessKey = process.env.secretAccessKey;
```

but still not getting any value for that.